# Laravel Autoclosing after clicking one request

Tags: laravel

I  have a problem when declaring autoload in laravel,
i have been using laravel 8 and php 7.4.3  this is the problem

[image]

After i get another request, the laravel runner always closing and give me this error

[image]

To solve this error, i've always do the

```
php artisan key:generate
```

or do another thing like restarting the laravel after dump autoload

```
composer dump-autoload
php artisan serve
```

But the problem just solve for one time, and it will be error again until i dump the composer again

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In your composer.json file you should have the following line

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
```

And in you artisan file you should have the following

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

The composer.json code should autoload any content coming from the App directory, while the require /vendor/autoloader will load vendor content into your project. Also you must have app.php inside of the bootstrap directory to allow the app to use the Kernal corrently. Hope this helps!

Comment: I have already those settings, but it still have the error